# Miktex installation failure?

Tags: miktex

I have tried to install MikTeX using the Net Installer (setup-2.9.6942-x64)
from a local repository that has the update of the 13 February but I am getting this error:

> An error occurred:
>     source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageDataStore.cpp
>     source line: 397
>     message: The requested package is unknown.
>     info: name="biber-windows-x64"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! This is probably a very silly question, but have you checked that your Windows version is compatible with what you want to install (32/64 bits)?

Comment: @manooooh: my windows is 10 64bit and it is compatible

Comment: Do you have biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma in your local repository?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: yes i do have biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma in my local repository

Comment: Are the package databases in the local repository in sync with the repository?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: yes  the local repository is  in sync with the repository (I did a full download and it completed with success)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the 13  February update. I downloaded a new update (18 February) and this solved the problem.